# Django How to get data from many to many fields?

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model for a week products menu. It has seven datefields, one user field (foreign key) and seven many2many fields. I can save data to database, all fine, except one thing: when I'm trying to get all menus or all user's menu - all chosen products from m2m fields ... gone. Ok, code:

```
models.py

# All info about product: name, type (name of table, more precisly), calories,...
class FoodProduct(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    prod_name=models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    prod_type=models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    prod_calories=models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    prod_proteins=models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    prod_fats=models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    prod_carbohydrates=models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.prod_name
    
    food = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Продукт"
        verbose_name_plural="Продукты"
        ordering=['prod_type','prod_name']

#model of week Product menu: 7 date fields, 1 foreign key (user), 7 m2m fields that directs to the food products

class ProductMenu(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    timestamp=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    monday=models.DateField("Понедельник", blank=True, null=True)
    tuesday=models.DateField("Вторник", blank=True, null=True)
    wednesday=models.DateField("Среда", blank=True, null=True)
    thursday=models.DateField("Четверг", blank=True, null=True)
    friday=models.DateField("Пятница", blank=True, null=True)
    saturday=models.DateField("Суббота", blank=True, null=True)
    sunday=models.DateField("Воскресенье", blank=True, null=True)
    list_of_selected_products_monday=models.ManyToManyField('FoodProduct',verbose_name="Лист продуктов на понедельник", related_name='monday', blank=True, default=None)
    list_of_selected_products_tuesday=models.ManyToManyField('FoodProduct',verbose_name="Лист продуктов на вторник", related_name='tuesday', blank=True, default=None)
    list_of_selected_products_wednesday=models.ManyToManyField('FoodProduct',verbose_name="Лист продуктов на среду", related_name='wednesday', blank=True, default=None)
    list_of_selected_products_thursday=models.ManyToManyField('FoodProduct',verbose_name="Лист продуктов на четверг", related_name='thursday', blank=True, default=None)
    list_of_selected_products_friday=models.ManyToManyField('FoodProduct',verbose_name="Лист продуктов на пятницу", related_name='friday', blank=True, default=None)
    list_of_selected_products_saturday=models.ManyToManyField('FoodProduct',verbose_name="Лист продуктов на субботу", related_name='saturday', blank=True, default=None)
    list_of_selected_products_sunday=models.ManyToManyField('FoodProduct',verbose_name="Лист продуктов на воскресенье", related_name='sunday', blank=True, default=None)
    user=models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser', on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        self.name=str(self.user)+', '+str(self.timestamp)
        return self.name

    product_menu=models.Manager()

    class Meta():
        verbose_name="Меню продуктов на неделю"
        verbose_name_plural="Меню продуктов на неделю"
        ordering=["timestamp"]
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(monday__iso_week_day=1, monday__isnull=False) | models.Q(monday__isnull=True), name='check_monday'),
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(tuesday__iso_week_day=2, monday__isnull=False) | models.Q(tuesday__isnull=True), name='check_tuesday'),
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(wednesday__iso_week_day=3, wednesday__isnull=False) | models.Q(wednesday__isnull=True), name='check_wednesday'),
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(thursday__iso_week_day=4, thursday__isnull=False) | models.Q(thursday__isnull=True), name='check_thursday'),
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(friday__iso_week_day=5, friday__isnull=False) | models.Q(friday__isnull=True), name='check_friday'),
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(saturday__iso_week_day=6, saturday__isnull=False) | models.Q(saturday__isnull=True), name='check_saturday'),
            models.CheckConstraint(check=models.Q(sunday__iso_week_day=7, sunday__isnull=False) | models.Q(sunday__isnull=True), name='check_sunday')
            ]
```

So, the main idea: 1 user can have several week_prod_menus. Constraints checking if chosen date is exactly chosen day of week (or it has to be null), but it doesn't check if all chosen dates in one week (maybe, later add this constraint). I'd like to add constraint: (date is null and m2m field is null), but django don't like expression `m2mfield__is_null=True` (any advices here too?).

my `forms.py`

```
class Menu(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = ProductMenu
        fields = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday',
        'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday',
        'list_of_selected_products_monday', 
        'list_of_selected_products_tuesday',
        'list_of_selected_products_wednesday',
        'list_of_selected_products_thursday',
        'list_of_selected_products_friday',
        'list_of_selected_products_saturday',
        'list_of_selected_products_sunday'  
        ]
```

my `view.py`

```
blah-blah-blah and main part:

user=request.user
user_product_menus=ProductMenu.product_menu.filter(user__username__iexact=user)
print(user_product_menus.values_list())

result:
<QuerySet [
(40, datetime.date(2020, 10, 23), datetime.date(2020, 10, 19), None, None, None, None, None, None, 1),

(42, datetime.date(2020, 10, 23), None, None, None, None, datetime.date(2020, 10, 23), None, None, 1)
]>
```

first elemetn is ID in database, second is timestamp, third - monday date, forth - tuesday,... , last element - user id

Where is my many to many values? How can I access it? They are saved in database. I did save it correctly with ```form.save_m2m()`` after instance saved and in database I have values saved, here's the screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7d27.png)

I guess the problem in saving data.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
            #fill the form
            form=Menu(request.POST)
            #get the user
            user=request.user
            #valid?
            if form.is_valid():
                #make an instance to save, but don't save, actually
                menu=form.save(commit=False)
                #set userfield value, I don't know why, 
                #but Menu(request.POST) doesn't fill that field
                menu.user=user
                #saving instance
                menu.save()
                #saving m2m <-------- Here is the problem? Maybe I saved instance without these fields
#and when I'm trying to get data in profile page - I'm getting only instance I saved first, but not all #data? 
#If so... how can I save it right? I can try to make a hidden field in html page and set it value through 
#javascript on load page and I can use only save() which saves and m2m fields, but that completly not #safe at all, 
#I don't wanna do this...
                form.save_m2m()
                print('example created')
            #redirect to profile page where 
            context={
            }
            return redirect('profile', username=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

All was fine, just my bad understanding of query sets.
Correct sequence of actions:

1. To access products that have been chosen by user in some menu, we need to get (litteraly) menu in which we want to show every chosen product. Yes, simple, logically, but I was exhausted and didn't want to ... Well, today it took me 15 sec to understand my mistakes.

```py
menu=ProductMenu.product_menu.get(id=your chosen id or something else)
```

My main mistake was: i cant get access to related fields without GETting certain menu in which I'm trying to get access.
2) In this object you can get access to related fields:

```py
products_for_monday=menu.list_of_selected_products_monday.all()
#or just in one string 1)+2)
products_for_monday=ProductMenu.product_menu.get(id=#).list_of_selected_products_monday.all()
```

That's all... Ye, dumb as hell.